# is there optimized way to calculate how many possible turn when moving random 2 elements from list_a to list_b?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 lists below

> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>
> b = []

1. move 2 random elements from a to b (e.g. 1, 5) ==> a=[2,3,4], b=[1,5]
2. move back 1 random elements from b to a (e.g. 1) ==> a=[1,2,3,4], b=[5]
3. move 2 random elements from a to b (e.g. 1,3) ==> a=[2,4], b=[1,3,4,5]
4. move back 1 random elements from b to a (e.g. 3) ==> a=[2,3,4], b=[1,4,5]
   .............
   repeat until a=[] and b=[1,2,3,4,5]

**My question is**:
I want to cover all run that can happen and each run should not overlap each other.

So is there any optimized way to find it?

Appreciate for your help.

Thanks,
Dale

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have specific issues in the implementation?

Comment: honestly, i have no idea for the implementation :(.

Comment: If you just want to know how many combinations there are, I'd try to approach this from a combinatorial angle.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with below solution:

```
import itertools
import random

class Test():
    a_list=[-4,-7,6,103]
    b_list=[]

    def combine(self,arr):
        combination = [i for i in itertools.combinations(arr, 2)]
        return combination 

    def move(self, a, b):
        for ii in self.combine(a):
            print 'combination: {}'.format(ii)
            print 'old_a %s' %a
            new_b = list(set(b).union(ii))
            new_a = [x for x in a if x not in ii]
            print '1. new_a: %s new_b: %s' %(new_a, new_b)
            # self.list_total.append(total)
            if len(new_a) > 0:
                new_a.append(min(new_b))
                new_b.remove(min(new_b))
                print '2. new_a: %s new_b: %s' %(new_a, new_b)
            if len(new_a) > 0:
                self.move(new_a, new_b)
            else:
                print ('------- END -------' )

    def main(self):
        self.move(self.a_list, self.b_list)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test().main()
```

but my solution seems not correct and still miss some cases. Your advice is highly appreciate!